# How to remove blank space top of the tableView in swift4?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

[image]

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(300, 0, 50, 0)
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
```

I have used viewForHeaderInSection where i called a custom cell. This is responsible for "Your Last Transaction" And also i used heightForHeaderInSection. still no idea how to remove the dark gray space

Comment: How to remove this darkGray space? i want to start myTableview after the view.

Comment: you need to set `heightForHeaderInSection`

Comment: Sir i have user the view for header in section. The last transaction is in my header section.

Comment: update your question with these method.

Comment: okay sir doing it accordingly

Comment: comment that line `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(300, 0, 50, 0)` and check

Comment: @Kuldeep sir if i comment that line that the tableView is starting from the top. the headerView is getting overlapped by the tableView and if i drag the tableView it not scrolling and the headerView is not visible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177329/discussion-between-kuldeep-and-gorib-developer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to storboard containing you controller.
2. Select controller having your tableview.
3. search for "Adjust ScrollView Insets" in attribution inspector at right side and uncheck it, see below image for help.

[image]

Comment: Okay sir.. checking it

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate the height of that blue view and set that height in -

**UIEdgeInsetsMake("here", 0, 50, 0)**

, Suppose your blue view height is 400 , then your EdgeInsets should be like this -

**UIEdgeInsetsMake(400, 0, 50, 0)**